# wpf button with foreground and background as image

Tags: wpf

In my wpf application I have a button. I want the button like to be background have an image and forground also have the image. How to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Karn

Answer (score 6):

Not sure I understand what you want here, but here's two examples

Two different Images for foreground and background

```
<Button Content="Button" FontSize="50" Margin="0,0,263,155">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Time.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Foreground>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\C1.png"/>
    </Button.Foreground>
</Button>
```

[image]

Same Image as Foreground and Background

```
<Button Content="Button"
        FontSize="50"
        Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Background}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Time.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I forgot about `ImageBrush`! That may be all the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to override the button's default appearance using a `Style` and / or a `ControlTemplate`.

For examples, you may want to see:

- [Using Templates to Customize WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx), from MSDN Magazine (great starting point!)
- [This StackOverflow question on creating image buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261908/wpf-how-to-create-image-button-with-template)

Feel free to provide more specifics or some code if you're having trouble, and we'll be able to help further.