# WPF image button control

Tags: wpf, button, controls

Long time is now that I have been searching for a quality **WPF image button control**. I need the button to consist of an **image only** and let me set image options for **hovering and pressing**. All current solutions on SO and the rest of the web include **CustomTemplate** based solutions that are not very friendly (i.e. [TriState Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491941/wpf-tristate-image-button)).

Maybe there is a set of controls like **Modern UI** or **MahApps** that someone could point me to that have this kind of button?

Comment: What is the problem with simply setting an Image as content of the button?

Comment: How about hover image and undesired border effects of the Button control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** This control can be reused throughout a project as many times as you need it acts exactly as any other control would and is used the same way as any other control library. There is no Border effect and you can add whatever hover effect you want. This is how it works.

Add a folder named CustomControls to your solution.

Create a custom control(WPF) named ImageButton in that folder. The custom control code goes in there.

Now a folder named Themes should have been created in your project with a resourcedictionary named generic.xaml inside it. Open it and use the resourcedictionary code.

Now add this to your window tag

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyProject.CustomControls"
```

Now you can use the control in that window as many times as you'd like just like a regular button by using the tag structure at the end of the answer.

Here is one that I made you can set the Image source, height and width all from your main window and all standard button events are there.

Here is the custom control

```
namespace MyProject.CustomControls
{
public class ImageButton : Button
{
     public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Source",
            typeof(Uri),
            typeof(ImageButton));

    static ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
    }

    public Uri Source
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the style in the resourcedictionary, you can add mouseover event and a button.pressed event in the triggers section or remove the triggers and set them on your window.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyProject.CustomControls">

<Style x:Key="{x:Type b:ImageButton}" TargetType="{x:Type b:ImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type b:ImageButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                    <Image x:Name="_Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="" TargetName="" Value=""/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="" TargetName="" Value=""/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To use it in your project add the namespace to the window and then the tag will be like this

```
<b:ImageButton Source="Image.png" Height="50" Width="50" Click="do_Something"/>
```

Comment: I am looking for a more generic control, not a template solution

Comment: what do you mean by more generic?

Comment: Library type, nicely wrapped control/dll etc.

Comment: I need easy of use and re-usability in general.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how this can work for you, let me know if you have any questions with it.

Comment: Not a library but will do :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you have: https://imagebuttonwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/70356

You'll have to download de code, compile it, and then use the generated DLL in your project.

Check the code, it's pretty easy to make, and following CJK instructions for the actual control you could've done it yourself in no time!

Comment: Says "project is not yet published" when I click on the link

Comment: True, can't publish it without uploading the code... Mpf! I'll try to find another place to upload it :/

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found another control made by other people, there in Codeplex... Updating my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one

```
    <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="Azure Automation.jpg"/>
    </Button>
```

Comment: No image hover effect this way.

Comment: @eYe In that case you need to write the template for Button