# Execute command on mouse click on image control wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, triggers, styles

There is a command property in wpf that I am trying to execute on an image click. I am basically changing the style of a scroller. I downloaded sample styles from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/f51ddf8c-5227-4f1b-a5df-ec3d1b3439ca/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx) and after changing my style I end up with something like:

[image]

ok so let me explain. on the top there is an arrow pointing upwards on top of an image. I plan to get rid of the top arrow but the reason why I need it is because in the xaml it has a command that when clicked it scrolls upward. the code for that up arrow is:

```
<RepeatButton
          Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
          Margin="0,15,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Background="#FFFFFFFF"
          Grid.Row="0"                                                                        
          Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"   <!-- This is the line that enables to scroll upwards when clicked -->
          theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="UpArrow"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
          <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4" ScaleY="2"/>
          </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>    
</RepeatButton>
```

In short I am interested in the following property:

```
Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
```

It would be nice if I could get rid of the top arrow and place that command in the image instead. The problem is that the image control does not have the property command. I know I can make the alpha of the top arrow equal to 0 and make it appear like there is only an image but I am curios of understanding how does this work and moreover I would like to add more functionality such as changing the image appearance on mouse enter etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a button with control template just having an image and bind to the
Command of the button. More on this can be found here:
[Attach ICommand in WPF UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643689/attach-icommand-in-wpf-usercontrol)

Comment: Exactly I just placed a button instead of an image. But for some reason when I leave the mouse down it does not work.

Comment: Try templating a RepeatButton instead, button raises event only once.

Answer (score 0):

Or try using eventtocommand available in mvvm light tookit